# What is ECC / HECC, how does it differ from asymmetric encryption?

Tags: cryptography

I'm relatively new to cryptography, and I would like to know what Elliptic Curve Cryptography and Hyper Ellipic Curve Cryptography (HECC)  are, and where they are intended to be used.  I have read about them, but I cannot imagine what they do.

**What is ECC, and the hyper form of ECC?**

edit: i found a tiny discription about ecc, in tag info:
*ECC stands for Elliptic Curve Cryptography. Elliptic curves are a mathematical structure which allow to define cryptographic operations on them.*, how should i interpret this?

Comment: @mentallurg looks like a pretty specific question to me. It may be a better fit at the [crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), and it's a bit broad, but your feedback hardly helps.

Comment: Questions at SO should show that the author has done some effort to answer the question. It means that the author has at least goggled for it, read Wikipedia and several detailed articles to this topic, and despite of this has not found the answer. But in our case the author has not done any effort. That's why I suggest to close this question.

Comment: mentalburg, * I have read about them*, as already mentioned, and you repeated Z.T

Answer (score 1):

[Elliptic-curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography)

[Hyperelliptic-curve cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_curve_cryptography)

Diffie Hellman, RSA, and ECC are all ways to implement asymmetric cryptography (not only encryption but digital signatures and key exchange). There are also additional ways to implement asymmetric cryptography, for example the active research on post quantum crypto.

For actual specific questions about the math, ask on [CryptoSE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/), but they will not help you if you do not demonstrate that you have made an honest effort to find the answer yourself.